# How to send an email with a filled form pdf as attachment in PHP?

Tags: php, pdf, email-attachments

I'm currently trying to send an email with a filled form pdf as attachment.

I'm using the FPDM library to fill my pdf :
https://github.com/codeshell/fpdm

Here is my code :

```
$textes = $this->session->flashdata('textes');
$pdf->Load($textes, true);
$pdf->Merge();

//Génération
$pdf->Output("F",$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "filledPDF.pdf");
```

And then I'm trying to send an mail with this filled pdf as attachment.
Here is my mailing method :

```
public function sendMailWithAttachment($siteURL,$htmlMessage, $object, $recipientMail, $title, $files, $filesnames, $cc = null)
{

    if (!preg_match("#^[a-z0-9._-]+@(hotmail|live|msn).[a-z]{2,4}$#", $mail)) // On filtre les serveurs qui rencontrent des bogues.
    {
        $passage_ligne = "\r\n";
    }
    else
    {
        $passage_ligne = "\n";
    }

    $message_html = "
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta charset=\"UTF-8\">
    </head>
    <body class=\"emb-font-stack-default\" bgcolor=\"#ffffff\">
        <center class=\"wrapper\" style=\"background-color: #f6f9fb;width: 100%;min-width: 620px;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%\">
          <table class=\"wrapper\" style=\"border-collapse: collapse;border-spacing: 0;background-color: #f6f9fb;width: 100%;min-width: 620px;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;table-layout: fixed\">
              <tbody>
                  <tr>
                      <td style=\"padding-top: 0;padding-bottom: 0;padding-left: 0;padding-right: 0;vertical-align: top\">
                        <center>
                          <table class=\"preheader\" style=\"border-collapse: collapse;border-spacing: 0;width: 100%\">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class=\"title\" style=\"padding-top: 8px;padding-bottom: 8px;padding-left: 32px;padding-right: 32px;vertical-align: top;color: #adb3b9;font-family: sans-serif;font-size: 11px;line-height: 13px;width: 50%;text-align: left\">
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                          </table>
                          <table class=\"header\" style=\"border-collapse: collapse;border-spacing: 0;width: 100%\">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                  <td class=\"logo\" style=\"padding-top: 16px;padding-bottom: 32px;padding-left: 0;padding-right: 0;vertical-align: top;color: #2f353e;font-family: sans-serif;font-size: 24px;line-height: 24px;letter-spacing: -0.02em\" align=\"center\">
                                      <center>
                                          <div id=\"emb-email-header\"><img style=\"border-left-width: 0;border-top-width: 0;border-bottom-width: 0;border-right-width: 0;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;display: block;Margin-left: auto;Margin-right: auto;max-width: 484px\" src=\"$logo\" alt=\"Logo CFA\" width=\"323\" height=\"62\">
                                          </div>
                                      </center>
                                  </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                          </table>
                        </center>
                      </td>
                  </tr>
              </tbody>
          </table>

              <table class=\"wrapper\" style=\"border-collapse: collapse;border-spacing: 0;background-color: #f6f9fb;width: 100%;min-width: 620px;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;table-layout: fixed\">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td style=\"padding-top: 0;padding-bottom: 0;padding-left: 0;padding-right: 0;vertical-align: top\">
                        <center>
                          <table class=\"lightest\" style=\"border-collapse: collapse;border-spacing: 0;width: 100%\">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                  <td style=\"padding-top: 0;padding-bottom: 0;padding-left: 0;padding-right: 0;vertical-align: top\" align=\"center\">
                                    <table class=\"one-col\" style=\"border-collapse: collapse;border-spacing: 0;Margin-left: auto;Margin-right: auto;width: 900px\">
                                      <tbody><tr>
                                        <td class=\"column\" style=\"padding-top: 0;padding-bottom: 0;padding-left: 0;padding-right: 0;vertical-align: top;text-align: left\">
                                          <div><div class=\"column-top\" style=\"font-size: 52px;line-height: 52px\">&nbsp;</div></div>
                                            <table class=\"contents\" style=\"border-collapse: collapse;border-spacing: 0;width: 100%\">
                                              <tbody><tr>
                                                <td class=\"padded\" style=\"padding-top: 0;padding-bottom: 0;padding-left: 90px;padding-right: 90px;vertical-align: top\">


                                <h1 style=\"Margin-top: 0;font-weight: 400;letter-spacing: -0.02em;font-family: sans-serif;font-size: 26px;line-height: 42px;Margin-bottom: 24px;color: #2e3b4e;text-align: center\">
                                **Title**
                                </h1>
                                <p style=\"Margin-top: 0;font-weight: 300;font-family: sans-serif;font-size: 16px;line-height: 26px;text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;Margin-bottom: 26px;color: #4e5561\">
                                $htmlMessage
                                <br><br> <i>**Name**</i>
                                <br><br><br>
                                <br>
                                </p>

                                                </td>
                                              </tr>
                                            </tbody></table>

                                            <table class=\"contents\" style=\"border-collapse: collapse;border-spacing: 0;width: 100%\">
                                              <tbody><tr>
                                                <td class=\"padded\" style=\"padding-top: 0;padding-bottom: 0;padding-left: 90px;padding-right: 90px;vertical-align: top\">

                                            <div class=\"btn\" style=\"Margin-bottom: 26px;text-align: center\">

                                                </td>
                                              </tr>
                                            </tbody></table>

                                          <div class=\"column-bottom\" style=\"font-size: 26px;line-height: 26px\">&nbsp;</div>
                                        </td>
                                      </tr>
                                    </tbody></table>
                                  </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                          </table>
                        </center>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>

          <table class=\"wrapper\" style=\"border-collapse: collapse;border-spacing: 0;background-color: #f6f9fb;width: 100%;min-width: 620px;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;table-layout: fixed\">
            <tbody><tr>
              <td style=\"padding-top: 0;padding-bottom: 0;padding-left: 0;padding-right: 0;vertical-align: top\">
                <center>
                  <table class=\"footer\" style=\"border-collapse: collapse;border-spacing: 0;background-color: #1a232b;width: 100%\">
                    <tbody><tr>
                      <td class=\"shadow\" style=\"padding-top: 0;padding-bottom: 0;padding-left: 0;padding-right: 0;vertical-align: top;font-size: 2px;line-height: 2px;background-color: #07090b\" background=\"https://i3.createsend1.com/static/eb/master/05-slate/images/footer-shadow.gif\">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td class=\"inner\" style=\"padding-top: 0px;padding-bottom: 0px;padding-left: 0;padding-right: 0;vertical-align: top\" background=\"https://i4.createsend1.com/static/eb/master/05-slate/images/footer.gif\" align=\"center\">
                        <table class=\"cols\" style=\"border-collapse: collapse;border-spacing: 0;width: 600px\">
                          <tbody><tr>
                            <td class=\"left\" style=\"padding-top: 0;padding-bottom: 22px;padding-left: 0;padding-right: 5px;vertical-align: top;color: #8e959c;font-family: sans-serif;font-size: 12px;line-height: 20px;text-align: left;width: 53%\">
                              <table class=\"social\" style=\"border-collapse: collapse;border-spacing: 0\">
                                <tbody><tr>
                                  <td style=\"padding-top: 0;padding-bottom: 14px;padding-left: 0;padding-right: 0;vertical-align: top\">
                                  <td class=\"spacer\" style=\"padding-top: 0;padding-bottom: 14px;padding-left: 0;padding-right: 0;vertical-align: top;font-size: 1px;line-height: 1px;width: 7px\">&nbsp;</td>
                                  <td style=\"padding-top: 0;padding-bottom: 14px;padding-left: 0;padding-right: 0;vertical-align: top\">
                                    <td class=\"spacer\" style=\"padding-top: 0;padding-bottom: 14px;padding-left: 0;padding-right: 0;vertical-align: top;font-size: 1px;line-height: 1px;width: 7px\">&nbsp;</td>
                                  <td style=\"padding-top: 0;padding-bottom: 14px;padding-left: 0;padding-right: 0;vertical-align: top\">
                                   </tr>
                              </tbody></table>
                              <div>**Name**<br>
                                <br>
                                **adress**<br>
                                **adresse comp**
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class=\"right\" style=\"padding-top: 0;padding-bottom: 22px;padding-left: 5px;padding-right: 0;vertical-align: top;color: #8e959c;font-family: sans-serif;font-size: 12px;line-height: 20px;text-align: right;width: 47%\">

                              <div class=\"spacer\" style=\"font-size: 1px;line-height: 20px\">&nbsp;</div>
                              <div>
                                <span class=\"block\">
                                  <span>
                                    <a style=\"color: #8e959c;text-decoration: none;transition: all 0.2s;\" href=\"#\">
                                      **phone**
                                    </a>

                                    <br>

                                    <a style=\"color: #8e959c;text-decoration: none;transition: all 0.2s;\" href=\"#\">
                                      **email**
                                    </a>

                                    <br>

                                    <br>

                                    <a style=\"color: #8e959c;text-decoration: none;transition: all 0.2s;\" href=\"www.website.com\">
                                      **website**
                                    </a>

                                  </span>
                                </span>

                              </div>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        </tbody></table>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody></table>
                </center>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody></table>
        </center>
   </body>
    </html>
    ";
    //==========

    //=====Création de la boundary
    $boundary = "-----=".md5(rand());
    //==========

    //=====Définition du sujet.
    $sujet = '=?utf-8?B?'.base64_encode(Subject).'?=';
    //=========

    //=====Création du header de l'e-mail.

    $header = "MIME-Version: 1.0".$passage_ligne;
    $header.= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative;".$passage_ligne." boundary=\"$boundary\"".$passage_ligne;
    $header.= utf8_decode("From: \"". **Name** ."\" <".**email**.">".$passage_ligne);
    $header.= "Reply-to: \"".**Name**."\" <".**email**.">".$passage_ligne;
    /*
    if($cc != null) {
        $header.= "Cc: " .$cc .$passage_ligne;
    }
    */


    //==========

    //=====Création du message.
    $message = $passage_ligne."--".$boundary.$passage_ligne;
    //=====Ajout du message au format HTML
    $message.= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"utf8\"".$passage_ligne;
    $message.= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit".$passage_ligne;
    $message.= $passage_ligne.$message_html.$passage_ligne;

    for($i=0; $i<count($files);$i++){
        $filesize = filesize($files[$i]);
        $handle = fopen($files[$i],"r");
        $content = fread($handle,$filesize);
        fclose($handle);
        $content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));

        //==========Ajout des fichiers joints
        $message .= "--" . $boundary . $passage_ligne;
        $message .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"" . $filesnames[$i] . "\"" . $passage_ligne;
        $message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64" . $passage_ligne;
        $message .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filesnames[$i]."\"".$passage_ligne . $passage_ligne;
        $message .= $content . $passage_ligne;

    }
    //Fin du mail
    $message .= "--" . $boundary . "--";

    //=====Envoi de l'e-mail.
    return mail($mail,$sujet,$message,$header);
    //==========
```

This "email sending" function works fine with normal pdfs but with mine, all texts and fields disappear. I would like to know if there is a way to do it or is it impossible ?

Also, I'm using PHP 7 with Code Igniter 3.

Comment: @Arlien - Please stick to English.

Comment: I would recommend that you use one of the tried and tested mail libraries, like Swift Mail, PHP Mailer or similar instead of using PHP's basic mail function. Those have pretty verbose API's.

Comment: Hey, are you sure you must put the files and their infos on the message variable and not the header ?

Comment: Ok, i'm gonna try mail librairies, thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, as what suggested @Magnus Eriksson, I tried to do my mailing function with PHPMailer. This is a lot easier than the basic mail function, but, this hasn't solve my problem. What I discovered is that opening it in the browser doesn't show fields, but when I download it from the browser, they are still here. So it kind of solve my problem, Thanks all !